# Android FIrebase- Querying by Value does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query an event by the user's unique id, but it won't return anything. Here's my code for the query:

```
Query events = mDatabaseEvents.orderByValue().equalTo("user1");
```

and here's my Firebase Database structure:

```
events: {
  -event1: {
  1: user1,
  2: user2,
  3: user3,
},
  -event2: {
  1: user4,
  2: user5,
  3: user1,
},
```

I believe it is not working because the data is set through a hashmap, so "user1" may not be always in the same spot in each event. How do I go about fixing this problem? Thanks

Comment: Please share your code that you tried so far, and post your firebase database structure.

Comment: Nothing about your current code actually does anything with the Firebase Database yet. It merely defines a query. If you want to retrieve the matching items from the database, you'll have to [attach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an "addValueEventListener" to actually get the data. Here is an example with "orderByKey", there will be little changes i suppose:

```
Query query = locationComment.orderByKey();
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
            return;
        }
        data.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ...
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

You can see more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430304/5309996

Comment: I am using the query  for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. How would I go about doing that?